# nightwatch.js internet explorer

Tags: javascript, selenium, e2e-testing, nightwatch.js

I'm using nightwatch for testing my javascript application. I need to be able to run cross-browser tests on local machine. Chrome and Firefox are OK, but when running test on IE, I got an error:

```
Running:  google.com
    TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at pass (C:\Users\Dávid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\api\
assertions\urlContains.js:23:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dávid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\night
watch\lib\core\assertion.js:94:23)
    at HttpRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dávid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
nightwatch\lib\index.js:299:20)
    at HttpRequest.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at HttpRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dávid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
nightwatch\lib\index.js:346:15)
    at HttpRequest.emit (events.js:118:17)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dávid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\nightwatch\lib\http\request.js:150:16)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

IEDriverServer is in version 2.45.0 as used selenium is. I'm using x64 version on 64b Windows 8.1. And I've already done the registry thing for IE11.

**Test file:**

```
module.exports = {
    'google.com': function(browser){
        return browser
            .url('www.google.com')
            .pause(5000)
            .assert.urlContains('google')
            .end();
    }
}
```

**nightwatch.json:**

```
{
    "src_folders" : ["./tests/e2e"],
    "output_folder" : "./tests/reports",
    "custom_assertions_path" : "",
    "globals_path" : "",
    "live_output" : false,
    "parallel_process_delay" : 10,
    "disable_colors": false,

    "selenium" : {
        "start_process" : true,
        "server_path" : "./bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar",
        "log_path" : "",
        "host" : "127.0.0.1",
        "port" : 4444,
        "cli_args" : {
        "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "",
        "webdriver.ie.driver" : "./bin/IEDriverServer.exe",
        "webdriver.firefox.profile" : ""
    }
},

"test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
        "launch_url" : "http://localhost:3001",
        "selenium_host" : "127.0.0.1",
        "selenium_port" : 4444,
        "silent" : true,
        "disable_colors": false,
        "screenshots" : {
            "enabled" : false,
            "path" : ""
        },
        "desiredCapabilities" : {
            "browserName" : "firefox",
            "javascriptEnabled" : true,
            "acceptSslCerts" : true
        }
    },
    "chrome": {
        "desiredCapabilities" : {
            "browserName" : "chrome",
            "javascriptEnabled" : true,
            "acceptSslCerts" : true
        }
    },
    "ie": {
        "desiredCapabilities": {
            "browserName" : "internet explorer",
            "javascriptEnabled" : true,
            "acceptSslCerts" : true
        }
    }
}
```

**run command:**

```
nightwatch --env ie
```

**It fails on this line:**

```
.assert.urlContains('google')
```

For all help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this issue by disabling IE protected mode for all zones and also by lowering the security to lowest possible level for all zones as well.

Answer (score 7):

I see you've got a solution, but having been through this myself, I thought I'd leave this here for future people.

[Selenium docs](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) say Internet Explorer requires specific configuration

- IEDriverServer needs to be in the path. My experience has been that using %PATH% is surprisingly flaky, and I either:

  - set `webdriver.ie.driver` to a path in the `cli_args` of nightwatch.json
  - start the Selenium Server by hand with `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=.\IEDriverServer.exe`
- Protected Mode in IE (Tools > Internet Options > Security) needs to be the same for all zones (as you've found!). I often test locally and on VMs, so I enabled it for Local and Trusted, rather than disable it for the Internet zone.
- Set zoom to 100% (although, you know, why wouldn't it be?)
- For IE10+, Enhanced Protected Mode needs to be disabled (Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Security). Pretty sure this is disabled by default on client versions of Windows, but enabled on server versions.
- For IE11+, do a reghack to facilitate the connection between the selenium server and the browser instance. In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE` add a DWORD for `iexplore.exe` and set it to `0`. If you're running 64-bit windows, that path becomes `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`.

One extra from my experience:

- If you're on 64-bit windows, don't be tempted by the 64-bit IEDriverServer. It's slow. "Slower than the old lady in front of you at the ATM" slow.

Comment: hey I'm trying to run selenium tests in IE driver, I'm having issues, especially clicking on elements when nativeEvents is set to true. What does your configuration look like when testing in IE?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your test and it works fine on my laptop with Nightwatch v0.6.13. Which version of Nighwatch do you use ? (npm list nightwatch -g)

Comment: nightwatch v0.6.13.  Did you copypasted everything including nighwatch.json? Which version of selenium have you used?